# LEFT JOIN Subtotal from the same TABLE

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I am new to SQL, I am trying to query from a ledger table
I have two Queries that I need to join into one table

1st Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 1
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, [Transaction Date], GETDATE()) <= 3
    AND [ITEMTYPE] = 'F-C'
    AND ([Description] NOT LIKE '%REFILE%'
        AND [Description] NOT LIKE '%CROSSOVER%')
    AND ([UserNAME] LIKE '%USER1%'
        OR [UserNAME] LIKE '%user2%'
        OR [UserNAME] LIKE '%user3%')
```

2nd Query:

```
SELECT [ENCID], SUM([Trans]) AS Total_Charges
FROM Table 1
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, [Transaction Date], GETDATE()) <= 3 
    AND [ITEMTYPE] IN ('C')
GROUP BY [ENCID];
```

I need to Left join the 2nd Query to the 1st Query on ENCID

THanks.

Comment: given you haven't shown the columns in first query that will be hard to anyone to determine!

Comment: Use a `CTE` or a `SubQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just join it. Nothing special about it, except that you have to remember to give an alias e.g. `Totals`

I have also changed your `DATEDIFF(MONTH, [Transaction Date], GETDATE()) <= 3` to `[Transaction Date] >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())`, to allow SQL Server to use indexes on [Transaction Date] column, if you have any.

Also leading wild card text searches e.g. `[UserNAME] LIKE '%user2%'` are slow, avoid them if you can: https://sqlperformance.com/2017/02/sql-indexes/seek-leading-wildcard-sql-server

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE 1 AS a
    LEFT JOIN
        ( SELECT [ENCID], SUM([Trans]) AS Total_Charges
        FROM Table 1
        WHERE [Transaction Date] >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
            AND [ITEMTYPE] IN ('C')
        GROUP BY [ENCID] ) AS Totals ON Totals.[ENCID] = a.[ENCID]
WHERE 
    [Transaction Date] >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
    AND [ITEMTYPE] = 'F-C'
    AND ([Description] NOT LIKE '%REFILE%'
        AND [Description] NOT LIKE '%CROSSOVER%')
    AND ([UserNAME] LIKE '%USER1%'
        OR [UserNAME] LIKE '%user2%'
        OR [UserNAME] LIKE '%user3%')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you introduce any joins (to tables or subqueries) it is vital that you refer to columns from those sources by aliases.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM TABLE_1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT [ENCID], SUM([Trans]) AS Total_Charges
            FROM Table_1
            WHERE [Transaction Date] >= DATEADD(month,-3,GETDATE())
                AND [ITEMTYPE] IN ('C')
            GROUP BY [ENCID]
            ) sq ON t1.[ENCID] = sq.[ENCID]
WHERE t1.[Transaction Date] >= DATEADD(month,-3,GETDATE())
    AND t1.[ITEMTYPE] = 'F-C'
    AND (t1.[Description] NOT LIKE '%REFILE%'
        AND t1.[Description] NOT LIKE '%CROSSOVER%')
    AND (t1.[UserNAME] LIKE '%USER1%'
        OR t1.[UserNAME] LIKE '%user2%'
        OR t1.[UserNAME] LIKE '%user3%')
```

NOTE: I have altered the way the dates are considered so that an index on [Transaction Date] could be utilized. Instead of calculating a number of months on every row, it is far more efficient to calculate a date then compare existing data to that value. For best performance try to avoid using functions on data in the where clause.

Comment: Its giving me the error "t1.Transaction Date Could not be bound"

Comment: I removed an alias reference "t1." from the subquery.